# Get number of table rows after hiding some rows

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the number of rows in a table such as...

```
<table>
   <tr id="siteA">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>siteA</td>
   </tr>

   <tr id="siteB">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>siteB</td>
   </tr>

   <tr id="siteA">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>siteA</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

With the following JQuery code...

```
var rowCount = $('table tr').length;
```

if the table is not altered the number of rows returned is 3.

After trying to hide a few rows such as #siteA and counting the number of rows again I still end up with 3.

```
$("tr#siteA").hide();
var rowCount = $('table tr').length;
```

How do I make sure the number of rows counted does not include the ones that have been hidden?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:visible` selector.

```
var rowCount = $('table tr:visible').length;
```

Comment: Bruvooo `:)` wat up! +1 indeed!